# Calculating BIC based on number of parameters in neural network and loss

Tags: neural-networks, aic, bic

I have implemented a variational autoencoder. Now, I would like to calculate the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) based on the number of parameters in the network and the loss. For example, let's assume we have the following values:

```
run 1: #Parameters = 51442, loss = 0.03456
run 2: #Parameters = 52341, loss = 0.0315
run 3: #Parameters = 55000, loss = 0.0122
```

For each of the runs I would like to calculate the BIC. How can I do this?